# dropping all requests for a specific domain

Tags: linux, iptables, proxy, port-forwarding

I'm on a simple linux proxy.  I'd like to add iptable rules to drop all requests for a specific domain. I figured I run a dig command to get the ip addresses for the domain and then add an iptable rule for each one.  It seems, however, that it doesn't work to bind to more than one ip address.  So, it seems I need to add ip ranges like this...

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -m iprange --dst-range 66.220.144.0-66.220.159.255 --dport 443 -j DROP
```

That seems to work.  However, it has proven pretty problematic to parse the output of dig and correctly create the appropriate iptable rules.  Is there a better way?

Comment: A better solution would be to work with the DNS requests. Either run a DNS proxy and filter the domain out, or do an iptables text match on the DNS queries and reject those packets.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  In this instance I don't think DNS will work because we only want it to apply to port 443 traffic not port 80 traffic.  As I understand it there is no way in a DNS request to distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify hostnames in `iptables` commands which will get resolved at rule-add time. Hostnames which resolve to multiple IPs are also supported, although they generate multiple rules.

```
% sudo iptables --append FORWARD --protocol tcp --destination www.google.com --dport 443 --jump DROP
% sudo iptables -nL FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            74.125.224.147       tcp dpt:443
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            74.125.224.145       tcp dpt:443
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            74.125.224.148       tcp dpt:443
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            74.125.224.144       tcp dpt:443
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            74.125.224.146       tcp dpt:443
```

Comment: Works in 99% of the cases. I tried with YouTube, and although IPTABLES/Netfilter performs the DNS resolution for the IP addresses as shown above, the access stills remains allowed. Maybe (I said maybe...), it has something to do with this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421493/blocking-youtube-not-working-for-google-chrome/421526#421526

Comment: Unsurprisingly, youtube, and any other site which regularly changes the IP addresses returned in a DNS response for the name, isn't going to work with an IP address-based filtering system.